# TikZ: Align array of matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\tikzset{
  matrixstyle/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={
      draw
    }
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \matrix (M) [matrixstyle]{
            .1 & .1 \\
            .1 & .1 \\
        };

        \begin{scope} [local bounding box=MA, shift={(M.west)}, left = 0cm of M.west]
            \matrix (M11) [matrixstyle]{
                .1 & .0  \\
                .5 & .0 \\
            };
            \matrix (M12) [matrixstyle, right = 0cm of M11]{
                .2 & .0  \\
                .3 & .9 \\
            };
            \matrix (M21) [matrixstyle, below = 0cm of M11]{
                .0 & .0  \\
                .0 & .2 \\
            };
            \matrix (M22) [matrixstyle, right = 0cm of M21]{
                .3 & .0  \\
                .3 & .9 \\
            };
        \end{scope}

        \matrix (N) [matrixstyle, left = 1cm of MA.west]{
            .2 & .2  \\
            .2 & .2 \\
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

The output should show six matrices. Four in the middle. And one matrix each on the right and left side of the matrix array. However, I did not manage to place the matrix M to the right of the matrix array MA. The error is probably in the following line

`\begin{scope} [local bounding box=MA, shift={(M.west)}, left = 0cm of M.west]`

What is the right way to do it? Why does my approach not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

matrices you can consider as nodes, so their positioning is with `positioning` library is straightforward:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 1mm and 2mm,
every matrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                      nodes={draw},
                      column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth}
                        ]
\matrix (m1) 
{
.2 & .2  \\
.2 & .2 \\
};
\matrix (m11) [above right=of m1.east]
{
.1 & .0  \\
.5 & .0 \\
};
\matrix (m12) [right=of m11]
{
.1 & .1 \\
.1 & .1 \\
};
\matrix (m21) [below right= of m1.east]
{
.0 & .0  \\
.0 & .2 \\
};
\matrix (m22) [right = of m21]{
.3 & .0  \\
.3 & .9 \\
};

\matrix (m2) [right = of m1 -| m12.east]
{
.2 & .0  \\
.3 & .9 \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `right = of m1 -| m12.east` mean? Especially the `-|` part.

Comment: Is it possible to define the four matrices in the middle as a single object that can be moved and resized? I want to resize the four matrices in the middle to have the same size as the matrices on the left and on the right.

Comment: @Samuel, this is new question in which you need to show (by sketch), how you like scale and shift a group of matrices. probably solution require a different solution as is shown in both answers.  i think, that both answers perfectly solve the problem described in this question, therefore it is time, that you accept one of them.

Answer (score 6):

Although not exactly the same, something very similar can be done with some `tabular` and without `TiKZ`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mytab}[4]{%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
        \hline
     #1&#2\\\hline
     #3&#4\\\hline
    \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\mytab{.2}{.2}{.2}{.2}\  
\begin{tabular}[c]{cccc}
\mytab{.1}{.0}{.5}{.2} & \mytab{.1}{.1}{.1}{.1}
\\[.5cm]
\mytab{.0}{.0}{.0}{.2} & \mytab{.3}{.0}{.3}{.9} 
\end{tabular}\ 
\mytab{.2}{.0}{.3}{.9} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: or even better with `ytableau` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\newcommand{\mytab}[4]{%
    \begin{ytableau}
     #1&#2\\
     #3&#4\\
    \end{ytableau}}

\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}

\mytab{.2}{.2}{.2}{.2}\  
\begin{tabular}[c]{cccc}
\mytab{.1}{.0}{.5}{.2} & \mytab{.1}{.1}{.1}{.1}
\\[.5cm]
\mytab{.0}{.0}{.0}{.2} & \mytab{.3}{.0}{.3}{.9} 
\end{tabular}\ 
\mytab{.2}{.0}{.3}{.9} 
\end{document}
```

[image]